# django duplicate SQL queries stemming from model method get_absolute_url that accesses ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django, django-views, query-optimization, django-queryset

### Problem Summary

I have a class-based list view that just displays links for each object along with some data from some of the object fields. The `href` for the links is generated using a `get_absolute_url` method that I've written in the model itself. The problem is that the database is queried each time get_absolute_url is run. This causes many duplicate queries (in the future, with more objects, this will be a problem).

### Attempted Solutions

My get_absolute_url method accesses some ForeignKey fields from my model, so I tried to use .select_related() for my queryset in  my view. This did not change anything though.

### Question

How can I eliminate the duplicate queries from running get_absolute_url?

## Code

### models.py

```
class LanguageLocale(models.Model):
    """model for representing language locale combinations"""

    class LANG_CODES(models.TextChoices):
        EN = 'en', _('English')
        ES = 'es', _('español')
        QC = 'qc', _("K'iche'")

    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LANG_CODES.choices, blank=False)

class Scenario(models.Model):
    """model for representing interpreting practice scenarios"""

    scenario_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

    lang_power = models.ForeignKey(LanguageLocale)
    lang_primary_non_power = models.ForeignKey(LanguageLocale)

    class SCENARIO_STATUSES(models.TextChoices):
        PROD = 'PROD', _('Production')
        STGE = 'STGE', _('Staged')
        EXPR = 'EXPR', _('Experimental')

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, choices=SCENARIO_STATUSES.choices, default='EXPR')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the URL to access a detail record for this scenario."""
        return reverse('dialogue-detail', kwargs={
            'lang_power': self.lang_power.lang,
            'lang_primary_non_power': self.lang_primary_non_power.lang,
            'pk': self.scenario_id
            }
        )
```

### views.py

```
class ScenarioListView(generic.ListView):
    """View class for list of Scenarios"""

    queryset = Scenario.objects.select_related(
        'domain_subdomain', 'lang_power', 'lang_primary_non_power'
    )
    
    demo = Scenario.objects.get(scenario_id='demo')
    prod = Scenario.objects.filter(status='PROD')
    staged = Scenario.objects.filter(status='STGE')
    experimental = Scenario.objects.filter(status='EXPR')
    
    extra_context = {
        'demo': demo,
        'prod': prod,
        'staged': staged,
        'experimental': experimental,
    }
```

### scenario_list.html

```
{% extends "home.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Practice Dialogues</h1>
  <section>
    {% if prod %}
      <ul>
        {% for scenario in prod %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ scenario.get_absolute_url }}">{{  scenario.title }}</a> ({{ 
            scenario.domain_subdomain.domain }})
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% else %}
      <p>There are no practice scenarios. Something went wrong.</p>
    {% endif %}
  </section>
  {% if user.is_staff %}
    <section>
      {% if staged %}
        <article>
          <h2>Staged Dialogues</h2>
          <ul>
            {% for scenario in staged %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ scenario.get_absolute_url }}">{{  scenario.title }}</a> ({{ 
                scenario.domain_subdomain.domain }})
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </article>
      {% endif %}
      {% if experimental %}
        <article>
          <h2>Experimental Dialogues</h2>
          <ul>
            {% for scenario in experimental %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ scenario.get_absolute_url }}">{{  scenario.title }}</a> ({{ 
                scenario.domain_subdomain.domain }})
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </article>
      {% endif %}
    </section>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

### duplicate queries readout (from django debug toolbar)

#### This query is duplicated 3 times:

```
SELECT "scenario_languagelocale"."id",
       "scenario_languagelocale"."lang_locale",
       "scenario_languagelocale"."lang"
  FROM "scenario_languagelocale"
 WHERE "scenario_languagelocale"."id" = 1
 LIMIT 21 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.
```

#### This query is duplicated 2 times:

```
SELECT "scenario_languagelocale"."id",
       "scenario_languagelocale"."lang_locale",
       "scenario_languagelocale"."lang"
  FROM "scenario_languagelocale"
 WHERE "scenario_languagelocale"."id" = 3
 LIMIT 21 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise *not* to use `extra_context`. This will prevent reevaluating the query between two requests, which means that if you thus add an extra `Scenario`, and you do not restart the server, it will not "update' the list when you ask for the scenario's again. The `demo` query is even more problematic, since that runs immediately when you *start* the server, and thus can raise errors if you run this on a server with a database, without such demo `Scenario`.

You can however work with `queryset` which already performs a `.select_related(…)` on the necessary relations here, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class ScenarioListView(generic.ListView):
    """View class for list of Scenarios"""
    queryset = Scenario.objects.select_related(
        'domain_subdomain', 'lang_power', 'lang_primary_non_power'
    )

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(
            *args,
            **kwargs,
            demo=get_object_or_404(self.queryset, scenario_id='demo'),
            prod=self.queryset.filter(status='PROD'),
            staged=self.queryset.filter(status='STGE'),
            experimental=self.queryset.filter(status='EXPR'),
        )
```

Comment: That did it. No duplicate queries whatsoever. Thank you for the best practices.